# Ones counter using numeric_std inside process

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I had an error while working on ones counter inside the process.
I use numeric_std library. Here is the key part of the code.

```
signal one_buf : unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal out_buf : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

counter_one : process(out_buf1)
  variable one_buf1 : unsigned(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
  for i in 0 to 7 loop
    one_buf1 := one_buf1 + unsigned(out_buf(i));
  end loop;
  one_buf <= one_buf1;
end process counter_one;
```

The error message is

> Error(10305) cannot convert type "std_ulogic" to type "UNSIGNED". 
>   I do not understand what is wrong here.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: A scalar type and an array type are not closely related, type conversion is not allowed. Noting you don't display a context clause or context items (which unsigned?) you could evaluate out_buf(i) in an if statement and add 1 to one_buf1, if true. Or you could use concatenation to create an array value from out_buf(i) (`one_buf1 := one_buf1 + unsigned("" & out_buf(i));`). Also one_buf1 wants to be assigned to all '0's before the for loop to make your process reentrant (one_buf1 will overflow eventually otherwise). Consider a function for hamming weight returning a natural instead.

Comment: This looks to me like a complete answer posted as a comment @user1155120

Comment: @scary_jeff - Nope, not an answer. There's another error in the process demonstrating the value of a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and incorrect syntax in my comment (that should be a qualified expression not a type conversion - `one_buf1 :=  one_buf1 + unsigned'("" & out_buf(i));` a missing apostrophe).

Comment: @user1155120 `"" & out_buf(i)` - thank you - I've learnt something.

Comment: You could while away an afternoon with the standard understanding why that works. The type of the null string depends on context, supplied by the qualified expression.